# Definition of limit point: Is the superset necessary?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Consider:

(A) The definition of a limit point from wiki: "Let S be a subset of a topological space X. A point x in X is a limit point of S if every neighbourhood of x contains at least one point of S different from x itself."

(B) Also note that: "A set is closed if it contains all of its limit points".

The second statement doesn't make any reference to the superset X. This implies that one can tell whether a point is a limit point without reference to the superset X. So I ask: Is the superset needed in the definition? And if it is, then isn't (B) vague?

Comment: (B) referes to limit points defined in (A), so it is not vague

Comment: Yes and yes. I would rephrase (B) as "A subset  $S$ of $X$ is closed in $X$ ..."

Comment: Keep in mind this is Wikipedia, and the text has been revised hundreds of times by several different people who each have their own styles. So we get such things as being told twice in the first three lines of the text that a limit point of $S$ does not need to be a member of $S$. One might be able to improve the text by editing it, but it doesn't pay to nitpick such things when you are merely reading.

Comment: B *does* make an oblique and indirect reference to the super set!  A set S is closed if all its limit points are in S.  But the limit points that *aren't* in S are ... *where*?  They have be in some other superset.  Example:  the set $(0, \sqrt {2}) $ is closed in Q because all its limit points **in Q** are in the set.  In R in set is NOT closed because all its limit points **in R*j are NOT in the set.

Comment: @fleablood So - if I can think ANY set with a limit point of S which is not in S, then S is not closed? This would be a final answer for me.

Comment: @user3141592 Good God!  Of course NOT!!!!!  Let Z be a set of invisible pink elephants that are infinitely close to every conceivable concept in the universe.  Let S = [0,1] the set of all real numbers between 0 and 1.  Then Larry the invisible pink elephant infinitely close to 1/pi is a limit point of S.  Larry is not in S.  So S is not closed.  That is obviously bullshit.  S is not closed **in the set that contains the set of invisible elephants**.  But S *is* closed in the Real numbers *which does NOT contain the set of invisible elephants*.

Comment: There is no such concept of a set being *objectively* closed. To be "closed" a set must be closed *with respect to some universal set*. That universal set must be stated or understood.*All* sets are closed with respect to themselves. No sets are closed in respect to a universe with my invisible pink elephants.The set S {all rationals whose square is less than 2} is closed in Q because it's limit points are all rational numbers less than sqrt 2 and they are all in S.  But S isn't closed in R because in R it has limit point all real numbers, irrational as well, less than or equal to sqrt 2.

Comment: Note the set [0,1] is closed in the reals.  It is not closed in the complex.

Comment: @fleablood That was great - if you paste it into an answer I would accept it. Of course it is only if you want to.

Comment: @fleablood: [0, 1] is certainly a closed set in the usual topology on the complex numbers.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury thanks, I was wondering about that bit. Also, I believe that $(0, \sqrt{2})$ is not closed in Q because of the 0 part. $[0, \sqrt{2})$ is probably what was meant. Nonetheless I found the point very clarifying.

Comment: Yeah, that was a really careless error on my part. [0,1] is most certainly closed in C. But I never claimed $(0,\sqrt{2})$ was closed in Q.  I said the rationals whose squares are less than 2 and that'd be $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ which is closed in Q.  Hmm, I'd like to come up with a set that is closed in R but not in C but I don't think that's possible as R is complete.

Comment: It's not possible because $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and closed subsets of closed subsets are closed.

Comment: Yeah that too.  ....

Comment: Actually, I don't think I was ever asked to demonstrate R was closed in C.  It's pretty easy to do.  ... as R is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $X$ can be closed or not, depending of where it is referred to.

(Or better yet: where it's neighborhood is defined; but a neighborhood is always a subset of the superset.)

#### Example 1:

Consider $\Bbb{R}$ the set of real numbers, and the set of rational numbers $\Bbb{Q}$.

$\Bbb{Q}$ is closed in itself, but not in ${\Bbb{R}}$.

More formally:

Let ${N_p}$ be a neighborhood of $p \in \Bbb{Q}$, such that ${N_p} \subset \Bbb{Q}$.

${N_p}$ is the set of every rational number $q \in \Bbb{Q}$ which the distance $d(p,q) < \epsilon$.

Make $\epsilon$ an irrational number.

For any (irrational) value of $\epsilon$, there will be $$q \neq p\ |\ q \in {N_p}$$

${N_p}$ is a closed set when referred to $\Bbb{Q}$ because it contains it's every accumulation point (limit).

#### proof:

If $d(p,q) > \epsilon$, then $q$ is not an accumulation point of $N_p$. Because
$$\exists \ N_q \ | \ N_q \cap N_p = \oslash$$

And if $d(p,q) < \epsilon$, then $q$ is an accumulation point of $N_p$. Because $$\exists \ N_q \ | \ N_q \cap N_p \neq \oslash$$

There is no $q$ such that $d(p,q) = \epsilon$. (That would make $q$ irrational.)

OBS.: a point $q$ is an accumulation point of $X$ if every neighborhood of it, $N_q$, contains a point $x \in X$

---

Now consider ${N_p} \subset \Bbb{R}$, and a point $q \in \Bbb{R}$.

$$\exists \ q \ | \ d(p,q) = \epsilon$$

$q$ is an accumulation point of $N_p$ because $$N_q \cap N_p \neq \oslash$$ and $$q \notin N_p$$

Thus $N_p$ is not closed.

---

Hence, to say that a set is closed or not you must define it's superset (where you are putting your neighborhood in).

Then yes, the superset is needed.

edit: (B) is a bit vague, but it is accurate to the definition of closed set.